# django output writing to a text file as temporary storage (over-written with each submission)

Tags: python, django, file-handling

I have managed to configure a system, using django, that allows me to upload a file to my media-folder. I have (using simple-html) included a drop-down menu that will specify parameters that will be considered when processing the uploaded file in a pipeline.

```
<form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

        <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

        <p>
            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
            {{ form.docfile }}
        </p>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
    <th>Genome Dataset</th>
     <TD WIDTH = 80% ALIGN=left VALIGN=top>
      <SELECT NAME='genome' ID='genome'>
        <OPTION>All</OPTION>
        <OPTION>Neanderthal</OPTION>
        <OPTION>hg38 Human</OPTION>
        <OPTION>Denisovan</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
    </tr>   
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
    </form>
```

I need to send the selected dropdown option to a text file. and I have attempted to do so as follows in views.py. However. while the file uploads to the media folder successfully, no text file manifests in the media folder- which is needed.

```
def GenomesView(request):
   if request.method == 'GET':
     getgen = request.GET.get('genome')
     content = ContentFile(getgen)
     f = open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'file.txt'), 'w')
     myfile = File(f)
     myfile.write(getgen)
     myfile.close()
```

The location of the media folder is as below in settings.

```
  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Hence my question is how do I take the selected option forms the drop-down and each time the file is uploaded to the site, the selection is sent to text file that will be over-written for each new submission (acting as a temporary storage for the selected option parameter i.e "Neanderthall" etc. as seen in code above)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a form to POST this data, but only writing to the file if the request is a GET. Try changing it to a POST. Also, since `request.POST.get('genome')` should return a string for you to write to the file there is no need to wrap it in a `ContentFile`. Try this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    getgen = request.POST.get('genome')
    with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'file.txt'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(getgen)
```

I also changed your [file handling to use a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: thanks for that, unfortunately it's still not working but we will continue to work on it :)

Comment: Elaborate on "not working". Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: sorry I meant no text file appears in the media folder at all (but the uploaded file does).... there are no actual errors.... we also considered the "tempfile" module as it may be more 'pythonic'